# button onclicks not working on certain elements

Tags: javascript, dom, events, onclick, event-handling

I am making a game in JavaScript. I am trying to create a button with an `onclick` element and attach it to the scene. I have already done this in several places, but now the code is failing. This is the (simplified) code that is *not* working:

```
const testme = document.createElement('input');
  testme.type = 'button';
  testme.value = 'click me';
  testme.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('clicked');
  });
  outputElement.appendChild(testme);
```

The button renders, but clicking on it does not trigger an effect. If I don't use an anonymous function, ie
`testme.addEventListener('click', alert('clicked'));` it acts as expected (running the code only once).

If I instead attach the element to document.body (`document.body.appendChild(testme)` the button works fine. Output is a normal div given by `const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');` I have other functions that use `outputElement.appendChild` which work fine:

```
function chooseName() {
  const nameInput = document.createElement('input');
  nameInput.type = 'text';
  nameInput.id = 'name-input';
  nameInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const playerName = nameInput.value.trim();
      if (playerName !== '') {
        setPlayerName(playerName);
        output(`Your name is ${getPlayerName()}`);
        gameState = 'chooseOccupation';
        document.getElementById('name-input').remove();
        promptOccupation();
      } else {
        output('Please enter a valid name.');
      }
    }
  });

  outputElement.appendChild(nameInput);
  nameInput.focus();
}
```

```
  const occupations = [
    'Archaeologist', 'Astrologer', 'Brewer', 'Burglar', 'Clergyman', 'Courier',
    'Dramatist', 'Ditch digger', 'Forester', 'Gambler', 'Hangman', 'Healer',
    'Jeweler', 'Netmaker', 'Ostler', 'Scribe', 'Taxidermist', 'Trapper',
    'Undertaker', 'Weaver'
  ];

  const occupationList = document.createElement('div');
  for (occupation of occupations) {
    const occupationButton = document.createElement('p');
    const job = occupation;
    occupationButton.textContent = occupation;
    occupationButton.classList.add('clickable-text');
    occupationButton.addEventListener('click', () => chooseOccupation(job));
    occupationList.appendChild(occupationButton);
  }
  outputElement.appendChild(occupationList);
```

Unfortunately, because this project is so large (5+ files, hundreds of LoC) I'm not sure how to make a reproducible example. I'm hoping somebody can tell me what *might* be causing this, as I am frankly out of ideas, and not an excellent JavaScript programmer.

EDIT:
I noticed if I put the test before chooseName(), like this:

```
function chooseName() {
  const testme = document.createElement('input');
  testme.type = 'button';
  testme.value = 'click me';
  testme.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('clicked');
  });

  const nameInput = document.createElement('input');
  nameInput.type = 'text';
  nameInput.id = 'name-input';
  outputElement.appendChild(testme);
  nameInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const playerName = nameInput.value.trim();
      if (playerName !== '') {
        setPlayerName(playerName);
        output(`Your name is ${getPlayerName()}`);
        gameState = 'chooseOccupation';
        document.getElementById('name-input').remove();
        promptOccupation();
      } else {
        output('Please enter a valid name.');
      }
    }
  });
```

It works, but only if I click the test button *before* I input a name. After I input a name, the test button does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "put the test before chooseName()"? What test?

Comment: When the second argument to `addEventListener()` isn't a function, it'e executed immediately like any other function argument, not when you click.

Comment: As for what might be causing this, maybe you have some other element that's overlaid over the button, so it's getting the click event instead.

Comment: @Barmar I mean, when I declare the testme button before the nameInput element, the button works until I use the nameInput element, at which point the testme button stops working. There isn't anything overlaid on top of the button, I use outputElement.appendChild() to write any created elements to the page, and other onClick() events (my occupationlist onclicks) are working.

Comment: The code that isn't working isn't even in a function, so it's hard to understand the difference between the working and non-working versions.

Comment: Unless you can post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, it's going to be hard for us to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

My `output()` function was modifying the innerHTML of outputElement, which destroys the listener. Using `outputElement.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead fixed my issue.